# Parameter Alignment in Pentaho Report Designer

Tags: report, pentaho, pentaho-report-designer

I am new to Pentaho Report Designer

**Version using**

1. Pentaho report designer 3.9
2. Pentaho BI Server 4.8

By default my reports display the parameters with the parameter label at the top with the drop-down field below.

When choosing the customer, the page currently it displays parameters like below.

Customer: 

 Drop Down Displays Here

I need to display the parameter like below

Customer: Drop Down Displays Here

Can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can get the labels to the side, but if you have multiple parameters, you can go to the Structure pane and select Master Report (at the top).  In the Attributes tab, for parameter-layout select either Horizontal or Flow.

I had a problem where there were too many parameters, and you couldn't scroll down to see all of them.

Answer (score 0):

You can just go to Sturcture -> Master Report.

Click on Master Report, then click on Attributes.

Under Attributes have a parameter section, look on parameter-layout.

There are 3 options to choose: vertical, horizontal and flow.

You can just choose this 3 options to adjust your parameter layout.

Hopefully can help you.